# Ajax request com setInterval que pisca

Tags: javascript, ajax

O seguinte pedaço de código tem como objetivo colocar o conteudo de um **ficheiro de texto** dentro de uma div.Como o **ficheiro de texto** pode ser atualizado, pretende-se que a div esteja atualizada com o conteudo mais recente do ficheiro. Mas a cada 2 segundos o conteudo da div pisca. Como posso atingir o mesmo obtjetivo sem que o conteudo da div pisque? Obrigado.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setInterval("loadXMLDoc()",2000);
   function loadXMLDoc(){
        var xmlhttp;
       // codigo para IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
           document.getElementById("minhaDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_doc.txt",true);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: Olá João, o que estás a fazer está no caminho certo. Eu mudaria para `setTimeout(loadXMLDoc, 2000);` a ser disparado dentro do `.onreadystatechange` para garantir que só tens uma chamada de cada vez. Em relação a "piscar" dá-me ideia que tens muito conteúdo e que o browser precisa de tempo para fazer a renderização... podes  mudar menos conteúdo de cada vez? E já agora podes clarificar na tua pergunta o que tem esse conteúdo? Imagens? só texto?

Comment: É preciso também verificar se o `responseText` já está disponível, pois o `onreadystatechange` é chamado várias vezes antes disso. Talvez seja a causa do problema.

Comment: O conteudo é apenas texto. É um ficheiro .txt com apenas duas palavras. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@João, realizei alguns testes aqui, o problema ocorria quando o `innerHTML` era substituído por um texto Longo.

Para contornar esta situação, fiz o seguinte.

1. Criei uma `div` chamada `container`
2. Adicionei o Texto a `div` `container`
3. Limpei a `div` `minhaDiv`
4. Adicionei a `div` `container`à `div` `minhaDiv`

Para a demostração abaixo, usei a API BaconIpsum para gerar um texto aleatório.

```js
setInterval(loadXMLDoc,2000);

var minhaDiv = document.getElementById("minhaDiv");
function loadXMLDoc(){
    var xmlhttp;
    // codigo para IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.responseText && xmlhttp.responseText.length > 0)
        {   
            var content = document.createElement("div");            
            var paragrafos = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            for (var i = 0; i < paragrafos.length; i++) {
                var paragrafo = document.createElement("p");                
                paragrafo.innerHTML = paragrafos[i];
                content.appendChild(paragrafo);         
            }
        
            if (minhaDiv.firstChild){
                minhaDiv.removeChild(minhaDiv.firstChild);
            }
            minhaDiv.appendChild(content);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=10&start-with-lorem=1",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Vou estudar o este codigo que me pareceu bastante bom. Pois existem exertos do codigo que dizem respeito à manipulação da DOM.

Comment: @TobyMosque Acho que meu comentário lá em cima pode ter te induzido a essa verificação de se a resposta está vazia, mas o melhor seria checar se a requisição está finalizada e foi bem-sucedida: `if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)`